# Inserir comentário através de function

Tags: vba, excel-vba, xls

Como inserir um comentário com o texto de uma célula através de uma function?

Answer (score 1):

### Código da UDF

Este é o código da função para adicionar comentário e opcionalmente, calcula algo na célula.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function AdicionarComentario(celula As Range, Optional Calcs)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    If TypeOf Application.Caller Is Range Then
        Dim Caller As Range
        Set Caller = Application.Caller
        Caller.ClearComments
        Caller.AddComment CStr(celula.Value)
    End If
    If Not IsMissing(Calcs) Then
        AdicionarComentario = Calcs
    Else
        AdicionarComentario = ""
    End If
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' error handling code
    AdicionarComentario = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

### Resultado

Inserindo a fórmula `=AdicionarComentario(D1)` em `E1`, adiciona um comentário com o texto da célula `D1` na célula `E1`.

[image: Resultado 1]

Inserindo a fórmula `=AdicionarComentario(D2;SOMA(E3;E4))` em `E2`, adiciona um comentário com o texto da célula `D2` na célula `E2`. E utiliza o campo opcional com `SOMA(E3;E4)`, em que realiza a soma de E3+E4 e retorna o valor deste cálculo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Opcional - Desccrição

A descrição pode ser adicionada executando este código uma vez.

```
Sub DescreverFunction()
   Dim FuncName As String
   Dim FuncDesc As String
   Dim Category As String
   Dim ArgDesc(1 To 2) As String

   FuncName = "AdicionarComentario"
   FuncDesc = "Adiciona comentário na célula e cálculos opcionalmente."
   Category = 14
   ArgDesc(1) = "Célula com o texto do comentário"
   ArgDesc(2) = "Cálculo realizado na célula"

   Application.MacroOptions _
      Macro:=FuncName, _
      Description:=FuncDesc, _
      Category:=Category, _
      ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End Sub
```

Com isso, a janela para inserir os argumentos da função possuirá a descrição para facilitar a vida do usuário.

[image: Argumentos da função]