# Tratamento de Erro Goto Não funciona em loop

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou com uma aplicação rodando em VBA, nele eu tenho um tratamento de erro que funciona perfeitamente na primeira vez que a ação passar por ele, porem ele esta dentro de um loop For Each e na segunda vez ele simplesmente ignora o tratamento, não sei se estou esquecendo de algum detalhe ou se ele simplesmente não roda quando chamado duas vezes em loop ou algo do tipo, alguém sabe o motivo desse acontecimento. Abaixo esta parte do código que esta dando esse erro.

```
On Error GoTo Erro
namePdf = doc3.Document.all.tags("font")(8).innerText

For Each exibirDoc In doc2.Document.all.tags("img")

    ver = exibirDoc.src

    If ver = "https://pan.interfile.com.br/imagens/FileSearch.gif" Then
         exibirDoc.Click
         Exit For
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Está esquecendo o mais importante, consertar o erro. Se ele continuar aí de nada adianta fazer mais nada. Tem uma forma ótima para ajudar, tire o "tratamento" de erro e deixe ele ser mostrado. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: Eu preciso que ele fique Maniero, não gosto de usar ele, mas nesse caso eu tive que usar.

Comment: Qual o código completo que trata o erro? `Erro:`

Comment: Elvis, na realidade não tem um tratamento especifico para este erro, eu apenas quero que ele redirecione a execução para determinada parte do algoritmo, para que ele continue sem travar o programa entende.

Comment: Qual é a parte do código em que ocorre mais erros? E como o @Elvis falou, você precisa fazer o `Erro:`, pois quando ocorre o oerro, você está falando para o código pular para `Erro:`, porém não há nenhum código `Erro:`... Veja [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254193/75104) em que em caso de erro, sai do `Sub`, porém você pode colocar também um `Exit For` em caso de erro. Para mais informações, tem [um tutorial em inglês sobre isto](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Comment: @danieltakeshi eu vou explicar melhor, eu tenho uma aplicação que procurar determinados documentos em um site especifico, porem quando o site não encontra documentos para downloads, ele me retorna um popup dizendo que não tem, é nessa hora que o programa da erro, e a melhor forma que eu achei para resolver isso é usar o GoTo. Mas ja achei uma forma de resolver isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma forma de resolver meu problema, joguei o trecho do código que localiza o erro em uma Sub separada, então eu chamo essa sub no código toda vez que a aplicação passar por ele, nesse momento o programa é redirecionado para essa sub e quando termina ele volta para a sub que esta antes e realiza o loop, dessa forma o GoTo sempre funciona em todas as voltas do For Each. Obrigado a todos que responderam, como eu disse, essa é uma forma de trabalhar com o GoTo mais de uma vez no algoritmo. 
Claro que usar esse método não é bem visto, mas foi a única forma que eu achei de trabalhar no meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Sempre que usar a instrução `On Error GoTo` para direcionar à alguma linha específica lembre-se de limpar a memória de erro utilizando `-1` e `0`. O código ficaria assim:

```
On Error GoTo -1
On Error GoTo 0
On Error GoTo Erro
namePdf = doc3.Document.all.tags("font")(8).innerText

For Each exibirDoc In doc2.Document.all.tags("img")

    ver = exibirDoc.src

    If ver = "https://pan.interfile.com.br/imagens/FileSearch.gif" Then
         exibirDoc.Click
         Exit For
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa solução a de "limpar a memória" com 0 e -1, porem só esqueceu de mencionar a sobre instrução
**On Error GoTo -1
On Error GoTo 0
On Error GoTo Erro**
tem que estar dentro do loop...

Pelo menos foi o jeito que funcionou aqui comigo.

Valeu Abraços...